# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) from Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, pg

I feel like I've tried everything. I have a cloud function that I am trying to connect to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL engine). Before I do so, I pull connection string info from Secrets Manager, set that up in a credentials object, and call a pg (package) pool to run a database query.

Below is my code:
Credentials:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const credentials: sqlCredentials = {
   "host":"127.0.0.1",
   "database":"myFirstDatabase",
   "port":"5432",
   "user":"postgres",
   "password":"postgres1!"
}

const pool: Pool = new Pool(credentials);

await pool.query(`select CURRENT_DATE;`).catch(error => console.error(`error in pool.query: ${error}`));
```

Upon running the cloud function with this code, I get the following error:

```
error in pool.query: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I have attempted to update the host to the private IP of the Cloud SQL instance, and also update the host to the Cloud SQL instance name on this environment, but that is to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi, can you try removing port from credentials and add it with host itself? like ```"port":"5432"``` and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 2):

Through much tribulation, I figured out the answer. Given that there is NO documentation on how to solve this, I'm going to put the answer here in hopes that I can come back here in 2025 and see that it has helped hundreds. In fact, I'm setting a reminder in my phone right now to check this URL on November 24, 2025.

Solution: The host must be set as:

```
/cloudsql/<googleProjectName(notId)>:<region>:<sql instanceName>
```

Ending code:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const credentials: sqlCredentials = {
   "host":"/cloudsql/my-first-project-191923:us-east1:my-first-cloudsql-inst",
   "database":"myFirstDatabase",
   "port":"5432",
   "user":"postgres",
   "password":"postgres1!"
}

const pool: Pool = new Pool(credentials);

await pool.query(`select CURRENT_DATE;`).catch(error => console.error(`error in pool.query: ${error}`));
```

Comment: This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions

Comment: The documentation is wrong and caused hours of hassle.

Comment: How so? It says exactly what your post says (which is to use /cloudsql/instance_connection_name)

Comment: It does not say that on the link you provided above.

Comment: It says: "Connect with Unix sockets
Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME." -https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#public-ip-default

Comment: That is not listed when connecting via private IP. In my original question, I listed connecting via private IP.

Comment: In that case, you are either actually connecting incorrectly. You're actually either connecting via public IP, or you are connecting via private IP but in a way that might change or break in the future. I would suggest following the directions on the page and using a serverless VPC connector and the instances IP as it describes.

Comment: I did follow the directions on the page, spending hours doing so, with no results.